# High Charts, pie chart customaization

Tags: jquery, highcharts

i have to do some customization like :
1. remove hand pointer on mouse over the pie slices.
2. display the label inside the large/big slice.
3. on mouseover/mouseout high light the respective div.

Reference img:
[image]
Here is the jsfiddle, which i have worked to implement the 3 point:
on mouse over i could highlight the selected, but on mouse out not able to remove the color

**HTML**

```
    <div class="grid_5">
<div class="grid_4" id="top_states_chart" style="min-width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div class="grid_4 right">
    <div class="Others level1">Maharastra</div>
    <div class="Firefox level2">Karnataka</div>
    <div class="level3">Gujarat</div>
    <div class="level4">Tamil Nadu</div>
    <div class="level5">Madhya Pradesh</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQquery**

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: ['#fffccc', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263',      '#6AF9C4']
       });
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Build the chart
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'top_states_chart',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            tooltip: {
                //pointFormat: '',//{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>
                //percentageDecimals: 1
                formatter: function() {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: false,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: false,
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            mouseOver: function(event) {
                                var point = this;


                                $('div.'+point.name).css({'background-color':'green', 'cursor':'pointer'});
                             }
                        }
                    },
                    events: {
                        mouseOut: function() {
                            //pieChart.tooltip.hide();
                            var point = this;

                            $('div.'+point.name).css({'background-color':'none', 'cursor':'pointer'});
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',

                data: [
                    ['Firefox',   45.0],
                    ['Others',   55.7]
                ]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XErNG/135/

please have a look at this js code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` as events.
Use `togleClass` to toggle style.

```
pie: {
    allowPointSelect: false,
    stickTracking: false,

    // solves problem 1
    cursor: 'normal',

    // the following solves problem 2
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        formatter: function () {
            return this.y;
        },
        distance: -30
    },

    // the following solves problem 3
    point: {
        events: {
            mouseOver: function() {
                $('div.' + this.name).addClass('highlight');
            },
            mouseOut: function() {
                $('div.' + this.name).removeClass('highlight');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your serie date should be:

```
data: [
    ['Firefox', 45.0],
    {
        name: 'Others',
        y: 55.7,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
]
```

Css

```
.highlight {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhAD8/)

Comment: hi Ricardo Lohmann, Thanks you very much for the answer, it works great with points 1 and 2 that i mentioned. But with point 3, solution that you have given is highlighting both the divs 
<div class="Others level1">Maharastra</div>
    <div class="Firefox level2">Karnataka</div>
At same time, when the user mouse overs on first slice and moves to slice 2. Can you please suggest me how this can be acheived

Comment: Hey Used :
 mouseOver: function () {
    $('div.' + this.name).addClass('highlight');
},
mouseOut: function () {

    $('div.' + this.name).removeClass('highlight');
}

Works now as expected, Thanks for your Help Ricardo.

Comment: Hey Ricardo Lohmann, is it possible to redraw the piechart like the one in the reference image attached, it looks like eclipse with drak shadow at right side, is this possible in highcharts? please suggest